# Sending an object in a function from html to code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Is it possible to send an element from the html to the code behind on event?
like that, for example:

```
<td id="id1" onClick="do1(id1)" runat="server"></td>
```

code behind:

```
protected void do1(object sender, EventArgs e,**var x**)
{
    x. Attributes.Add("class", "class1");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't send an element from the html to the code behind the way you wrote above. However if you want to add a value for an attribute of a server control (html elements that have the runat="server"), you can. Please tell us what's the attribute you want to add and I will include the corresponding piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

If it were javascript then you can use the "this" keyword:

```
<td id="id1" onClick="do1(this)"></td>
```

"this" means "id1". You can also write your function like this:

```
function do1(){
   var x = document.getElementById("id1");
   //do sth with x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do in the code behind is add a CSS class, why not do it via javascript?

html:

```
<td id="id1" onClick="changeClass()"></td>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeClass()
{
document.getElementById("id1").className = "class1";
}
</script>
```

If you need to run your method from the codebehind you will have to post back the page for the code to ever get reached.

Comment: because i need to do more then then. if there is a way to both active a function in the code behind and a function in javascript, that will do, is know of?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to run JS code, update CSS and run some code behind.  You can do this with the code above, you just need to add a form submit at the end of the javascript method.  Add this line in the method:   document.forms[0].submit();